# How to crop an image in a QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, crop, qrubberband

I have to develop an image editor. The last feature I'm missing for it is cropping the image using a `QRubberBand`, and then crop the selected area using a push button.

There are reports of subclassing `QGraphicsView`, but I don't know how to connect it to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to build a [QRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#details) with the area of the picture that you want to keep.

Then you can use the [copy](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qimage.html#copy) method on QImage to create a new picture containing only the rectangle area.

```
QRect rect(10, 10, 30, 30);  //X Y top left corner coordinates ,  width / height of the rectangle

QImage croppedImage = initialImage.copy(rect);
```

Next use a [QGraphicsPixmapItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspixmapitem.html) to add your picture in the scene :

```
  QGraphicsPixmapItem *unitaire = new QGraphicsPixmapItem();
   unitaire ->setPixmap(mySprite);
  m_scene->addItem(unitaire );
```

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to select the Area using my Mouse with MouseEvents. And the Problem is that I want to Crop the Image on the start point (press) and end point (release), inside the GraphicsView

Comment: My answer is still correct, you will have to the copy() to get the cropped picture. But if you want to use the mouse to get the image corners (to create the "rect"), you can use an event filter to catch the mouse coordinates on your scene and the buttons status.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html